# How do I import scss file in Nativescript Vue?

Tags: javascript, nativescript, bulma, nativescript-vue

In `app.scss` file, I import css as follows:

```
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/button.sass";
```

Tried even by removing `../node_modules/`, the css is still not working. The styles won't apply at all. Please help.

Comment: Your browser doesn't understand SASS/SCSS. It must be compiled into CSS and then imported.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to import bulma source code? Did you alter anything? If not, you can just include the bulma .css file.

Comment: Try `~` right before the package name. Something like `@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";` I hope your webpack config is updated to support sass.

Comment: It doesn't work  even if I use bulma.css! The styles won't apply at all.

Answer (score 0):

Bulma will not work with NativeScript-Vue.

NativeScript has its own components and CSS properties. NativeScript is not HTML and not normal CSS (even if sometimes they are very similar). Some things *could* work, but I would not follow this route, though. If nothing else, because it will load a bunch of unused CSS.

Even so, the proper way to `@import` CSS/SCSS from `node_modules`, assuming you have the default webpack config, would be:

```
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/all";
@import "~bulma/sass/elements/button";
```

Comment: But I should be able to at least to import buttons css.

Comment: Edited my answer. I hope it helps.